# MX QR Code Generator: "cannot decode raw data"

Tags: add-on

I'm trying to use the MX QR Code Generator and using a very basic example from the website like so;

```
<img src='{exp:qr_code type="" action="tel" tel="1234567" data="ExpressionEngine" title=""}' alt="QR code"/>
```

When I load the page Safari just throws "Safari can’t open the page “http://mydomain.tld”. The error is: “cannot decode raw data” (NSURLErrorDomain:-1015)" error.

There is a type parameter in the code as well, but the documentation on the site has no reference to this.

Comment: Does safari throw that error for the generated image, or the page that contains it?

Comment: Hey Adrian. It's the whole page that is replaced with that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>I made quick update - try a version 2.0.5.</strike> 
you can find example on [demo-ee](http://demo-ee.com/examples/view/qr-codes-generator)

ok. the issue was with image folder - if you use not standart image folder ('/images/'):

```
img src="{exp:qr_code type="" action="" tel="" data="asdasd" title="" email="" subj="" size="10" alt="QR code" base_path="SERVER_PATH_TO_WEB_ROOT"  base_cache="SERVER_PATH_TO_QR_CODE_IMAGE_FOLDER"}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive, but I'm pretty sure you shouldn't be using the `data="ExpressionEngine"` parameter when you're using the `tel` action. I think it's an either/or situation with tel/data/email parameters. The `data=""` parameter is used for URLs and other data types.

Comment: Hey Jeremy,Sorry - didn't seem to get a notification of your reply. I removed the data="ExpressinoEngine" but still seemed to get the error. I think it must be due to the type="" but I can't seem to find a reference to what needs to be passed in there. :/

Comment: I'd suggest leaving type="" out. It looks like it accepts type="J" if you want the QR code to be a JPEG otherwise it comes out as a PNG.

Comment: Yeah, I tried leaving it out altogether but it still borked. :( Shame there isn't another plugin that does the same sort of thing that works. Heh.

Comment: Yeah. Hm. I will check it out later today. I know I've used it before without an issue.